# sed: use regular expression to get rid of <img ...> part

Tags: html, regex, linux, sed

For the text `ABC<img src="test"></a>`, I'm hoping to get rid of the `<img ...>` part, in other words, I want the result to be displayed as: `ABC</a>`. I tried several patterns, but none of them worked.

```
echo 'ABC<img src="test"></a>'|sed -e "s/<img src=\".*>//g"
ABC
```

I don't know whether I should escape `<` or `>`, When I did, I got the following result:

```
echo 'ABC<img src="test"></a>'|sed -e "s/\<img src=\".*\>//g"
ABC<>
```

Can anyone clarify these results and give me a satisfying one?

Comment: Mandatory link: [don't parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552)

Comment: @MarkZar so did my solution work to you? Otherwise I will delete it.

Comment: @fedorqui Oh, sorry. I thought I had accepted it. I've no idea I forgot it or it was due to network problem. Anyway, thank you. It worked very well.

Comment: @MarkZar no problem :) Glad that it worked to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just indicate that you want to remove from `<img` + any set of characters until a new `>` is found.

```
sed "s/<img[^>]*>//g"
```

#### Test

```
$ sed "s/<img[^>]*>//g" <<< 'ABC<img src="test"></a>'
ABC</a>
```